# SQL CopyFromRecordSet got slow without a reason in VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel, adodb

I have a procedure in VBA that I've been using for some time now to pull the data set from SQL DB.

It always took less then 1 min to populate the template but since few days it's been taking more than 10 mins. Nothing changed in the database, nothing changed in my VBA code either:

It gets stuck on:

```
Sheets("NEW").Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rst
```

I even upgraded from Office 2013 to 2016 but the issue still persists. Any guesses what could be the reason?

My code

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String
Dim Combine As String
Dim ow As Long
Dim ok As Integer
Dim i As Long

 ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Data Source=xxxx;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=Share_Assignment_Automation"


    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = "SELECT [Organization],null as [ERP Segment 1],[Effective date of assignment to Team],[Expiration date of assignment to Team],null as [Last Modified By],null as [Last Modified Date],[Territory Type Name],[Forecastable Flag],[Inside Sales Flag] FROM [vw_SHARETeam] with (nolock) "

    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
    Sheets("TEAM").Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
```

Comment: i ve updated my post with the code, however i doubt it's code-related issue as , as i said, it used to work fine  for the couple of weeks and suddenly  it got slower

Comment: First thing you should is get rid of that nolock hint. It is NOT a magic go fast button. It has some very serious ramifications far beyond what most people realize. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: As for the issue of performance we need some details. Why do you think it is the query that is slow? Can you post an actual execution plan? That looks like a view, are the nested?

Comment: when i run the code step by step (F8) it's smooth until  it gets to mentioned line: Sheets("TEAM").Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rst   where it stucks for abt 10 mins. Also, when running query directly in SQL, it takes  less than minute to pull entire table

Comment: So it isn't the query that is slow...although a minute for a query seems pretty slow to me. How many rows are we talking about here?

Comment: there's 54 000 rows and 34 columns in total. It's view  of a table with some filters set  hence it takes  about a minute, i guess. The thing is, when i  sent the worksheet to  two of my colleagues to test, it worked fine ( total time+- 1 min)  that's why  i suppose it might be related  to some settings  in  office/windows general ?

Comment: Do you have any add-ins running in your Excel instance?  If Yes then try disabling them and repeat the query.

Comment: no add-ins. Even extracted the code  to  separate blank Workbook just in case  nothing interfere the  query, still the same.

Comment: are you using a remote sql server? maybe your firewall changed? throttled connection ?

Comment: it's not remote server. Firewall settings have not been changed, windows updateds are  disabled. Just in case i installed office 2016 and removed 2013 entirely, still no success, it's really mistery for me....:<

Comment: Does `packet size=32767` make any difference?

Comment: thanks Jeroen Mostert, it actually helped, it is still  quicker on other PCs regardless of packet size used but  it really  decreased  time needed to execute on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. My query was 7 seconds but the paste was 60 seconds. (100,000 rows).
The issue was that I was pasting into an excel table which was auto-expanding its range.
I changed my code to disable auto-expand, then paste data, then manually expand the table range. This now takes 15 seconds total.